# SpringBoot. Controller does not read CheckBox values

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, checkbox, controller

I have Form with CheckBoxes on my index.html.

```html
            <form name="formCheckBox" id="formCheckBox" action="/filter" method="POST">     
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="onechange" name="onechange" onclick="this.form.submit();">
                  <label for="onechange">one change</label>
                </div>            
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="nochanges" name="nochanges" onclick="this.form.submit();">
                  <label for="nochanges">no changes</label>
                </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to read values of both Checkboxes (on or off) in Controller after clicking on any Checkbox (need a page update). And feels like It does not go to Controller at all. So, how to read it in Controller and How to send those values back on my new page filter.html?

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/filter")
    public String checkBoxAction (@RequestParam("onechange") String onechange,
                                  @RequestParam("nochange") String nochange){
        System.out.println(onechange);
        System.out.println(nochange);
        return ("/filter");
    }
```

Comment: You may need values assigned to your checkbox in your template.

Comment: OK, I did, but it did not fix the problem

Comment: WOW. Found partial answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359851/how-to-receive-html-check-box-value-in-spring-mvc-controller Still do not know how to manage it from controller on new page

Comment: Second portion of the answer: https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/how-to-add-checked-attribute-to-input-conditionally-in-thymeleaf The question can be closed. Thank you!